# Linux (Mint 21) Issue with network constantly "changing", interrupts browsing and streaming

Tags: networking, linux-networking

I've been having problems with my network on this laptop for ever amen, it was only today whilst troubleshooting an unrelated issue that I ran `dmesg -w` and saw this constantly repeating:

```
[437075.730012] device vethbb6f6b7 left promiscuous mode
[437075.730015] br-4afae7cda0db: port 1(vethbb6f6b7) entered disabled state
[437078.163874] br-4afae7cda0db: port 1(veth4ba1c2c) entered blocking state
[437078.163890] br-4afae7cda0db: port 1(veth4ba1c2c) entered disabled state
[437078.164203] device veth4ba1c2c entered promiscuous mode
[437078.617428] eth0: renamed from veth6e3c7e1
[437078.657066] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth4ba1c2c: link becomes ready
[437078.657182] br-4afae7cda0db: port 1(veth4ba1c2c) entered blocking state
[437078.657190] br-4afae7cda0db: port 1(veth4ba1c2c) entered forwarding state
[437089.929739] br-4afae7cda0db: port 1(veth4ba1c2c) entered disabled state
[437089.929960] veth6e3c7e1: renamed from eth0
[437090.604513] br-4afae7cda0db: port 1(veth4ba1c2c) entered disabled state
[437090.606654] device veth4ba1c2c left promiscuous mode
[437090.606674] br-4afae7cda0db: port 1(veth4ba1c2c) entered disabled state
[437093.182216] br-4afae7cda0db: port 1(veth702be27) entered blocking state
[437093.182228] br-4afae7cda0db: port 1(veth702be27) entered disabled state
[437093.182534] device veth702be27 entered promiscuous mode
[437093.481225] eth0: renamed from veth392f810
[437093.497161] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth702be27: link becomes ready
[437093.497254] br-4afae7cda0db: port 1(veth702be27) entered blocking state
[437093.497260] br-4afae7cda0db: port 1(veth702be27) entered forwarding state
[437103.692753] veth392f810: renamed from eth0
```

(etc. forever)

The network mostly work, but I frequently get "Network changed" errors in the browser (a refresh usually sorts it). Recently, trying to download any large files has resulted in multiple interruptions.

Has anyone else seen anything like this, and could maybe give me some pointers?

I have numerous other machines on this network (both wired & wireless) and all seem to run flawlessly - it's just this laptop that suffers...

Cheers,
Ade.

System Info as follows:

```
  Kernel: 5.15.0-71-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.3.0 Desktop: Cinnamon 5.4.12
    tk: GTK 3.24.33 wm: Mutter dm: LightDM Distro: Linux Mint 21 Vanessa base: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Notebook product: NS5x_NS7xPU v: N/A serial: <superuser required>
    Chassis: No Enclosure type: 10 serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: Notebook model: NS5x_NS7xPU serial: <superuser required> UEFI: INSYDE v: 1.07.06
    date: 04/20/2022
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 71.5 Wh (100.0%) condition: 71.5/73.9 Wh (96.7%) volts: 8.4 min: 7.7
    model: Notebook BAT serial: <filter> status: Full
CPU:
  Info: 12-core (4-mt/8-st) model: 12th Gen Intel Core i7-1260P bits: 64 type: MST AMCP
    arch: Alder Lake rev: 3 cache: L1: 1.1 MiB L2: 9 MiB L3: 18 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1648 high: 4157 min/max: 400/4700:3400 cores: 1: 2131 2: 4157 3: 1117
    4: 2057 5: 728 6: 679 7: 1604 8: 869 9: 1432 10: 833 11: 2041 12: 919 13: 1514 14: 3194 15: 2627
    16: 478 bogomips: 79872
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics vendor: CLEVO/KAPOK driver: i915 v: kernel
    ports: active: DP-5,DP-6,eDP-1 empty: DP-1, DP-2, DP-3, DP-4, DP-7, HDMI-A-1 bus-ID: 00:02.0
    chip-ID: 8086:46a6
  Device-2: Chicony USB2.0 Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo bus-ID: 3-7:4 chip-ID: 04f2:b6f9
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X: loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa
    gpu: i915 display-ID: :0 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 10752x2160 s-dpi: 104
  Monitor-1: DP-1-1 pos: primary,top-center res: 3840x2160 dpi: 80 diag: 1395mm (54.9")
  Monitor-2: DP-1-2 pos: top-right res: 3840x2160 dpi: 80 diag: 1395mm (54.9")
  Monitor-3: eDP-1 pos: bottom-l model: BOE Display res: 3072x1728 dpi: 227 diag: 395mm (15.5")
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Graphics (ADL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 22.2.5 direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio vendor: CLEVO/KAPOK driver: snd_hda_intel
    v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:51c8
  Device-2: JMTek LLC. USB PnP Audio Device type: USB driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid
    bus-ID: 3-6.1.3:8 chip-ID: 0c76:153f
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-71-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel pcie: speed: 5 GT/s lanes: 1
    bus-ID: 2b:00.0 chip-ID: 8086:2723
  IF: wlp43s0 state: up mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: CLEVO/KAPOK
    driver: r8169 v: kernel pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1 port: 3000 bus-ID: 2d:00.0
    chip-ID: 10ec:8168
  IF: enp45s0 state: down mac: <filter>
  Device-3: ASIX AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet type: USB driver: ax88179_178a bus-ID: 2-1.2:9
    chip-ID: 0b95:1790
  IF: enxf8e43bad3673 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-1: br-4afae7cda0db state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: unknown mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-2: br-c3eb7622418e state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: unknown mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-3: docker0 state: down mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-4: veth029f25a state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-5: vethd6b2055 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel AX200 Bluetooth type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8 bus-ID: 3-10:5 chip-ID: 8087:0029
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: <filter> bt-v: 3.0 lmp-v: 5.2
    sub-v: 237e
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 465.76 GiB used: 228.3 GiB (49.0%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: SSD 980 500GB size: 465.76 GiB speed: 31.6 Gb/s
    lanes: 4 serial: <filter> temp: 38.9 C
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 456.89 GiB used: 228.3 GiB (50.0%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 511 MiB used: 6.1 MiB (1.2%) fs: vfat dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 137.8 MiB (6.7%) priority: -2 file: /swapfile
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 71.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Repos:
  Packages: apt: 2548
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/1password.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/1password-archive-keyring.gpg] https: //downloads.1password.com/linux/debian/amd64 stable main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https: //download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy stable
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kicad-kicad-6_0-releases-jammy.list
    1: deb http: //ppa.launchpad.net/kicad/kicad-6.0-releases/ubuntu jammy main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kicad-kicad-7_0-releases-jammy.list
    1: deb http: //ppa.launchpad.net/kicad/kicad-7.0-releases/ubuntu jammy main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
    1: deb http: //packages.linuxmint.com vanessa main upstream import backport
    2: deb http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted universe multiverse
    3: deb http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
    4: deb http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    5: deb http: //security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn3.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64] https: //swupdate.openvpn.net/community/openvpn3/repos jammy main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list
    1: deb https: //deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable non-free
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list
    1: deb https: //ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/jammy pgadmin4 main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/scootersoftware.list
    1: deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/scootersoftware-keyring.gpg] https: //www.scootersoftware.com/ bcompare4 non-free
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/slack.list
    1: deb https: //packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian/ jessie main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stripe-cli.list
    1: deb https: //packages.stripe.dev/stripe-cli-debian-local stable main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/teams.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64] https: //packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] http: //packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources
    1: deb [arch=amd64 i386] https: //dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy main
Info:
  Processes: 581 Uptime: 5d 1h 27m Memory: 31.06 GiB used: 15.02 GiB (48.4%) Init: systemd v: 249
  runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 11.3.0 alt: 11/12 Client: Cinnamon v: 5.4.12 inxi: 3.3.13
```

Comment: What type of network is port #1: Ethernet, Wifi or something else?

Comment: Hi, it's a good question - the adapter kept changing name & wasn't on the list anytime I `ifconfig`'d it... actually, It was a docker process spinning its wheels i.e. in a crash-restart cycle...

Comment: `ifconfig` is deprecated. Use `ip addr show` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Neppomuk's question, I dug a little deeper this morning - and it looks like it was a Docker container stuck in a crash/restart cycle.

Gotta love Docker!